# SQL Server T-SQL Trigger fires stored procedure AFTER UPDATE to linked Oracle server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I am having some difficulty getting a trigger to function properly in SQL Server 2012.  I have gotten to the point where I successfully created a stored procedure that fetches matching rows in a linked Oracle server and loads them into a temporary table for processing, and attempted to call this procedure via the code below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgr_ORACLE_myTable] ON  [dbo].[myTable]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @var1 varchar(50),
  @var2 varchar(50),
  @var3 int,
  @var4 int,
  @var5 bigint,
  @var6 bigint,
  @var7 varchar(50),
  @var8 datetime

IF UPDATE(field1) OR UPDATE(field2) OR UPDATE(field3)
  BEGIN
  DECLARE loop CURSOR FOR
  SELECT I.var1,
    I.var2,
    I.var3,
    I.var4,
    I.var5,
    I.var6,
    E.var7, 
    E.var8
  FROM inserted I

  OPEN loop
  FETCH NEXT FROM loop INTO @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN
    EXEC spORACLE_CheckAndUpdate @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8
    FETCH NEXT FROM loop INTO @var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8
    END

  CLOSE loop
  DEALLOCATE loop
  END
END
```

And here is the logic in the stored procedure itself:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spORACLE_CheckAndUpdate]
(
  @var1 varchar(50),
  @var2 varchar(50),
  @var3 int,
  @var4 int,
  @var5 bigint,
  @var6 bigint,
  @var7 varchar(50),
  @var8 datetime
)

AS

-- Do a grab of the information from Oracle
CREATE TABLE ##ORACLEData
(
  ID1 varchar(50),
  ID2 varchar(50),
  NUM1 int,
  NUM2 int
)

DECLARE @ID1 varchar(50),
    @ID2 varchar(50),
    @NUM1 int,
    @NUM2 int

DECLARE @linkedServer varchar(4000),
    @openQuery varchar(4000),
    @TSQL varchar(4000)

SET @linkedServer = '[MYORACLELINKEDSERVER]'
SET @openQuery = 'INSERT INTO ##ORACLEData (ID1, ID2, NUM1, NUM2) SELECT ID1, ID2, NUM1, NUM2 FROM OPENQUERY(' + @linkedServer + ','''
SET @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ORACLE_TABLE WHERE ID2 = ''''' + @var2 + ''''''')'
EXEC(@openQuery + @TSQL)

SELECT @ID1 = ID1,
  @ID2 = ID2,
  @NUM1 = NUM1,
  @NUM2 = NUM2
FROM ##ORACLEData

IF @ID1 IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN -- I found a matching record for this record in ORACLE
  IF @ID1 <> @val1 OR @NUM1 <> @var3 OR @NUM2 <> @var4
    BEGIN -- It's different in SQL Server and Oracle

    INSERT INTO myLog (ORACLEID1, ORACLEID2, ORACLENUM1, ORACLENUM2)
    VALUES (@ID1, @ID2, @NUM1, @NUM2)
    END
  END

DROP TABLE ##ORACLEData -- Clean up / drop the global temporary table
```

My intent here is to write another OPENQUERY statement to actually update the values in the Oracle server, instead of actually storing these values in the myLog table.  However, I can't even get the query to load the values in properly. When I run the stored procedure in query analyzer with the appropriate parameters, it works perfectly, but in the trigger, it fails. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edited to add:

I got it working using the "command" table idea, however I am being told that this needs to be a real-time update, and at the very least run no less than every 2 minutes.  I am not sure if this is still the correct approach.  Obviously the trigger isn't going to work... but are there any other options?

Comment: PHEW - a **cursor** inside a **trigger**, calling out to an external, linked server...... if that doesn't kill **ALL** your system performance, I don't know what else might....... seriously: **DO NOT** put heavy-duty processing into a trigger! That's just asking for performance issues....... only make a note into a "command" table in your trigger, and let a separate, async process (a scheduled SQL Server job or something) handle the actual heavy-lifting, to avoid severe performance problems....

Comment: LOL Thank you!  I KNEW this was a bad idea and got a good laugh out of this. The other option I was thinking about was what you suggested here with the SQL Job with temp tables indicating rows that need updating on each respective DB.